# Github mosaicshapes use

Tags: python, windows, github

Would like to use this GitHub code on my own pictures. I'm a total rookie and need advice on how to use this (I'm on pc Windows 11, already have Python downloaded on my computer but have many error messages on every step)...

https://github.com/helenst/mosaicshapes

Comment: I have edited the answer to address the `ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named "distutils"` error.

Answer (score 0):

ok, just to understand you well, do I have to modify the code in IDLE shell?

Cause when I'm typing this in cmd.exe  python run.py ./input/bryan.jpg -e 2000 -d -c 1 -o./out.jpeg

nothing's happen ( a new line appear).

thanks for all your time.

Roger

Comment: Try and comment under your own question, starting with `@VonC`: that will avoid leaving answers which are not answer (do not forget to delete them). Try putting a space between `-o` and `./out.jpeg`.

Comment: @VonC ok thanks. Nothing happen with a space between -o and ./out.jpeg

Comment: @VonC oook finally found it!!! Thanks for all your help, I'm going to make a statue of you in my town.

Comment: Great, what did you found out to make it work?

Comment: And don't forget to follow [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how the site is supposed to work.

Answer (score -1):

The sequence should be:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/helenst/mosaicshapes.git
cd mosaicshapes
pip install -r requirements.txt
python run.py [path_to_your_photo] -e 2000 -d -c 1
```

> I get: `usage: run.py [-h] [-d] [-c {0,1,2}] [-a] [-r WORKING_RES] [-e ENLARGE] [-m MULTI] [-p POOL] [-o OUT] N [N ...] run.py: error: the following arguments are required: N`

The error message is indicating that the argument `N`, which is the path to your photo, is required.

You need to replace `[path_to_your_photo]` with the actual path to your image file.
For example, if your photo is named "`picture.jpg`" and is located in the same directory as `run.py`, the command would be:

```bash
python run.py picture.jpg -e 2000 -d -c 1
```

---

> I got the error "`ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named "distutils"`"

The error `ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named "distutils"` occurs because the `distutils` module is not installed in your Python environment. This module is part of the standard library in Python versions prior to 3.10. If you are using Python 3.10, it has been removed and you would need to use a previous version of Python. To resolve this issue, you could:

1. Install an earlier version of Python (e.g., Python 3.9 or earlier).
2. After installing the earlier version of Python, activate its environment and re-run the commands to execute the script.

(Since [commit cf7e1ee](https://github.com/helenst/mosaicshapes/commit/cf7e1eed82a8691f131b8673024c5ad721f7eb3e) says "update requirements for python 3", I will assume you need Python 3. But not too recent!)

---

> Now have this error message: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/out.JPEG'`

That comes from [run.py#main()](https://github.com/helenst/mosaicshapes/blob/60d9d3f8d1fe5b36138cfffdc081cfeaa5c1a11c/run.py#L74): the default output (`--out`/`-o`) parameter is `/tmp/out.JPEG`.

That is inconvenient, especially on Windows.

Try adding an additional parameter `-o ./out.JPEG` to use the current folder, instead of a non-existent (on Windows) `/tmp` folder.